# Using Sum on a list of data

Tags: list-manipulation, data

i have 3 lists called Fi,Ti and Si, that go from 1 to 17. Each i corresponds to a certain value, i.e.

```
f = {0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10};
Ta = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1.05, 1.15, 1.3, 1.5, 1.7, 1.9, 1.1, 0.5, 0.01, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001}
Sui = {0.00126182, 0.00126182, 0.00126182, 0.00126181,
0.0012618, 0.00126178, 0.00126175, 0.00126172, 0.00126153, 0.00126064, 0.00125915, 0.00125708, 0.00125443, 0.0012512, 0.00124742, 0.00124308};
```

I am trying to compute the sum of the image attached (tried to paste the equation, but doesn't show in a mathematical form). Sorry my first time posting a question. Any advice ?

[image]

Comment: How are you defining `fn`,`tn`?

Comment: fdata = {0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
  7, 8, 10} and Ta = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1.05, 1.15, 1.3, 1.5, 1.7, 1.9, 1.1, 0.5, 0.01, 
  0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001}

Comment: Please include all the needed information, including su, in your question itself.

Answer (score 1):

Given (I added an extra element to `Su` as it seemed to be one short)

```
f = {0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
   6, 7, 8, 10};
Ta = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1.05, 1.15, 1.3, 1.5, 1.7, 1.9, 
  1.1, 0.5, 0.01, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001};
Su = {0.00126182, 0.00126182, 0.00126182, 0.00126181, 0.0012618, 0.00126178, 
  0.00126175, 0.00126172, 0.00126153, 0.00126064, 0.00125915, 
  0.00125708, 0.00125443, 0.0012512, 0.00124742, 0.00124308, 0.001};
```

The "Mathematica" way is

```
Total[Differences[f] (Drop[Su Ta^2, -1] + Drop[Su Ta^2, 1])]/2
(* 0.0104223 *)
```

The literal way is

```
Sum[1/2 (f[[i + 1]] - f[[i]]) (Su[[i]] Ta[[i]]^2 + Su[[i + 1]] Ta[[i + 1]]^2), {i, 1, 16}]
(* 0.0104223 *)
```

Comment: yep, i forgot the last element. it was: 0.0012328. Nevermind. Thanks a lot for your help. Appreciate it. Gonna look through these commands to fully understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use subscripts for this kind of thing, they are best at display. You can directly index into your arrays:

```
Total[0.5 Table[(f[[i + 1]] - f[[i]]) (su[[i]] Ta[[i]]^2 + 
      su[[i + 1]] Ta[[i+1]]^2), {i, 1, Length[f] - 2}]]
```

Comment: Why `Length[f]-2` shouldn't it be `Length[f]-1`?

Comment: worked. thanks a lot for your help and fast reply. I would like to add a "newbie" question. Which is the role of the gaps in-between the equation u posted ? e.g. (f[[i+1]] - f[[i]]) GAP (su[[i]] GAP Ta[[i]]^2 ....

Comment: @bill s, isn't putting `Total` round a `Table` redundant?  Wouldn't `Sum` be better?

Comment: The gaps (spaces) are multiplication. I tend to use Total[Table[ ]] rather than Sum[ ] because it is easy to look at the elements of the Table and make sure they are correct. But yes, you can save a few characters with Sum.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the [`Subscript`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subscript.html) form of [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html). I have used `ta` and `su` since you should not begin variables with a capital letter. I also added `0.001` to the end of `su` as it only has 16 entries.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or in `InputForm`

```
Sum[(1/2)*(f[[i + 1]] - f[[i]])*(su[[i]]*ta[[i]]^2 + 
    su[[i + 1]]*ta[[i + 1]]^2), {i, 1, 16}]
```

You can enter the subscript form of `Part` by surrounding the indices in the subscript with the part double square brackets.  Either `[[` and `]]` or <kbd>Esc</kbd>+`[[`+<kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd>+`]]`+<kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Hope this helps.